# Deploying a MongoDB database

Tags: python, mongodb, heroku

I'm building a small Webapp. I use MongoDB to retrieve and store my data, at the moment everything is working perfectly fine, but now I want to host my app online.

I know how to deploy my script on Heroku, but I don't know how it should work with MongoDB, maybe adding MongoDB to my app's requirements?

I made some research and found about Mlab, there is an Heroku add-on for it but sadly Mlab is going to migrate to Atlas soon

Comment: could you specify if you are using django/flask or what libraries?

Comment: @Mr-Programs i'm using Dash!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(edited, just say you added about mlab being migrated, [AWS](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas) also offers the same sandbox options as mlab on atlas as you said, you can also install it locally and add it to your settings.py)

## local setup

1. download a free MongoDB database at https://www.mongodb.com
2. **PyMongo** Python needs a MongoDB driver to access the MongoDB database.  use PIP to install "PyMongo"

---

### mlab sample setup

[image]why don't you have a look at one of my projects and see how i deployed *mongo* on a **CDN**

I used this site to make a sandboxed **FREE** CDN database https://mlab.com/

stick with this line where we are using the database from a CDN, this way we don't even need to install it on our system!

> // this is our MongoDB database, change this to CLOUD MONGO link const
>   dbRoute = "mongodb://*****:******@******.mlab.com:*****/*********";

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const logger = require("morgan");
const Data = require("./data");

const API_PORT = 3001;
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();

// this is our MongoDB database, change this to CLOUD MONGO link
const dbRoute = "mongodb://*****:******@******.mlab.com:*****/*********";

// connects our back end code with the database
mongoose.connect(
  dbRoute,
  { useNewUrlParser: true }
);

let db = mongoose.connection;

db.once("open", () => console.log("connected to the database"));

// checks if connection with the database is successful
db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "MongoDB connection error:"));

// (optional) only made for logging and
// bodyParser, parses the request body to be a readable json format
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(logger("dev"));

// this is our get method
// this method fetches all available data in our database
router.get("/getData", (req, res) => {
  Data.find((err, data) => {
    if (err) return res.json({ success: false, error: err });
    return res.json({ success: true, data: data });
  });
});

// this is our update method
// this method overwrites existing data in our database
router.post("/updateData", (req, res) => {
  const { id, update } = req.body;
  Data.findOneAndUpdate(id, update, err => {
    if (err) return res.json({ success: false, error: err });
    return res.json({ success: true });
  });
});

// this is our delete method
// this method removes existing data in our database
router.delete("/deleteData", (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.body;
  Data.findOneAndDelete(id, err => {
    if (err) return res.send(err);
    return res.json({ success: true });
  });
});

// this is our create methid
// this method adds new data in our database
router.post("/putData", (req, res) => {
  let data = new Data();

  const { id, message } = req.body;

  if ((!id && id !== 0) || !message) {
    return res.json({
      success: false,
      error: "INVALID INPUTS"
    });
  }
  data.message = message;
  data.id = id;
  data.save(err => {
    if (err) return res.json({ success: false, error: err });
    return res.json({ success: true });
  });
});

// append /api for our http requests
app.use("/api", router);

// launch our backend into a port
app.listen(API_PORT, () => console.log(`LISTENING ON PORT ${API_PORT}`));
```